# How deploy an Angular 2 application to windows server(IIS)?

Tags: angular, build, webpack, publish, webdeploy

At the moment when I build my Angular 2 application, I need connect to windows server using RDP and copy/paste folder with the built project. I want do it automatically. My build config based on   https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter (Angular 2 + Webpack).

I have idea with FTP. I can install FTP on windows server and after I will transfer file using my config file. But I think exist better way for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can open your deploy folder as a share folder and directly copy paste to the share folder, or copy to share folder then execute a copy script

For something more complicated, assuming you have your project on some sort of version control, you can manage a build process through [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)
and have it clone your repo and write a script to build/copy/deploy your project to the proper directory.